# Cant use JSON Stream for JSON Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jsonstream

I am working on big JSON data and used JSONStream npm module for parsing it. I can parse data from JSON Array Object. But one of scnerios get a simple JSON object(not array).

In this case, I am not able to parse multiple fields. I am able to parse/extract only one field.

My Json Structure, i want to parse/extract `status.replicas` and `status.updatedReplicas`

[image: JSON-Structure]

My code,

```
request({url:'ssss',verify:'False',headers:{'Authorization':'Bearer zzzz','Accept':'application/json','User-Agent':'zzz'}})
  .pipe(JSONStream.parse('status.replicas'))
  .pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
    console.log("Log "+data); 
  })) ;
```

This is giving `data =1` how can I parse both `replicas and updatedReplicas`

If I use `JSONStream.parse('*')` then output `data = Deployment` it is taking only `kind` element form my JSON.

Comment: Why not simply use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) or [`.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)?

Comment: Ok, I forgot to mention this in the question. The Json is very big and I cant use Json.parse as I am only getting a small chunk of data. json.parse is giving `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is access `status`, and then use `data.updatedReplicas` & `data.replicas`

```
request({url:'ssss',verify:'False',headers:{'Authorization':'Bearer zzzz','Accept':'application/json','User-Agent':'zzz'}})
  .pipe(JSONStream.parse('status'))
  .pipe(es.mapSync(function (data) {
    console.log("Log ", data.replicas, data.updatedReplicas); 
  })) ;
```

Note: `event-stream` has been archived

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I do remember using the same thing(code - `JSONStream.parse('status')`) and it did not work earlier. Now it is working as expected. Guess I need to sleep for some time :) Thanks again.